# Visual Studio Copilot is not Providing Suggestions

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I cannot find a way to get Copilot to write suggestions.  I've followed all setup instructions per the referenced documentation, uninstalled, reinstalled, verified compatibility, account linked, etc., and everything appears to be enabled but suggestions are never generated.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.7.4

GitHub Copilot v1.137.0.0

ASP.NET Core 6 project

[image]

The GitHub Copilot icon shows white with no issues.  The disable/enable is from me toggling the setting.  I don't see any other settings that could affect why this might not be working.

Ctrl+Alt+\ does nothing and Ctrl+Alt+Enter or clicking the "Open Copilot" throws this exception.  The screen capture shows the error thrown when pressing Ctrl+Alt+Enter after the desired suggestion, but also does the same when selecting it from the Copilot menu.

Is this a known issue or is there a workaround I can try here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the IntelliCode component since there's no purple lightbulb next to the Copilot icon.

First step for fix is to launch VS Installer, click "Modify" and make sure IntelliCode is selected. If it is already select, go back to VS Installer main page and "Repair" your install. Let me know if the IntelliCode icon is missing even after repair.